# How to growing UItextview on tableview cell based on data size using autolayouts

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i am beginner in ios and in my project i have added two textviews on tableview cell and they need to growing based on data size

According to my code first textview is not growing and second textview is growing based on data size,What did i do here wrong please help me some one

**Here is the code:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        formulaText = [[UITextView alloc]init];
        formulaText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0f];
        formulaText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        formulaText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        formulaText.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        formulaText.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:formulaText];

        formulaText1 = [[UITextView alloc]init];
        formulaText1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:15.0f];
        formulaText1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        formulaText1.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        formulaText1.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        formulaText1.scrollEnabled = NO;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:formulaText1];

        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(formulaText,formulaText1);

        NSArray * formulaH = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[formulaText]-10-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views];

        NSArray * formulaH1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[formulaText1]-10-|"
                                                                     options:0
                                                                     metrics:nil
                                                                       views:views];

       NSArray * textFieldConstraintV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[formulaText]-10-[formulaText1]-|"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:views];

        [cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaH];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:formulaH1];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:textFieldConstraintV];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert My code in swift yourself.

My code is not constraint based B'coz i'm not get constraints but the logic is perfect for me without constraints.

In below code i have one label in cell and it will growable and it's position is x=20,y=5,width = 255,height = growable.

you can use heightForRowAtIndexpath method

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //get string from array using indexpath 
    CGSize newLabelsize = [strComment sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"CenturyGothic" size:10] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    //Give your font and it's size for calculating data size.
   //in the above strComment is a string put in textview and 
  //width of your textview = width and
  //MAXFLOAT = height for grow and it is a macro so you can put it directly.
  //now you have new size of the textview so calculate with other outlet and return new height of the cell.

    return 5+newLabelsize.height+5; 
    // last +5 is for bottom space of label.
    // first 5+ is y pos of you of label.

}
```

The above code is just fix your cell size

Now same calculation in your cellforrow method for setting textview size

```
CGSize newLabelsize = [strComment sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"CenturyGothic" size:10] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

cell.textview.frame = CGRectMake(cell.textview.frame.origin.x,cell.textview.frame.origin.y,cell.textview.frame.size.width,newLabelsize.height);
```

And now you finally got you want.
Hope this helpful for you.

thanks you!